# Backbone.js appending [] to key name on fetch

Tags: django, backbone.js

I'm working on a Django + BackboneJS application.

On a given step of my flow I have the following fetch on my collection:

```
loadAdsByPlace: function(filters, placeID, place_child_list, page, success_func){
    var self=this;

    var data = {page: page,
                        placeID: placeID,
                              placeChildIDList: placeChildIDList};

    data["rooms"] = this.buildRoomsFilter(filters);
    data["bathrooms"] = this.buildBathroomsFilter(filters);

    var fetchOptions = {data: data, reset: false, remove:false, success:success_func, error:success_func};
    this.fetch(fetchOptions);

},
```

The request is successfully hitting my views.py, I can see it printing request.GET to console, but what I'm getting is:

```
<QueryDict: {u'rooms': [u'5'], u'placeID': [u'538a8cd7beac9e1a33977449'],  u'placeChildIDList[]': [u'525464', u'526706'], u'page': [u'1']}>
```

The problem is it returning:

```
u'placeChildIDList[]': [u'525464', u'526706']
```

while i expect

```
u'placeChildIDList': [u'525464', u'526706']
```

Can't get the reason. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `traditional` option to `true` when performing the fetch.

```
var fetchOptions = {data: data, reset: false, remove:false, success:success_func, error:success_func, traditional:true};
this.fetch(fetchOptions);
```